# How can I control the width of a label tag?

Tags: html, css, label

The label tag doesn't have the property 'width', so how should I control the width of a label tag?

Comment: Label is an inline element, it cannot have width value; in order to do this you need to put `display:block` or `float:left`.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Using CSS, of course...

```
label { display: block; width: 100px; }
```

The `width` attribute is deprecated, and CSS should always be used to control these kinds of presentational styles.

Comment: But that leads to a break in the code, which is probably what the OP **doesn’t** want in the first place.

Comment: @Konrad Then the OP can use `float` or `display: inline-block`

Comment: Yup, that’s what I wanted to get at. :-) This is the core aspect here, since it’s the difficult part. Merely setting `width` won’t have much use.

Comment: @JoshStodola oh shiiiiit..... inline-block never used to work for me, i tried float and bham! i wonder why inline-block did't work for me

Comment: @lostchild inline-block does not ignore whitespace, that might be why you were having issues with it.

Answer (score 113):

Using the inline-block is better because it doesn't force the remaining elements and/or controls to be drawn in a new line.

```
label {
  width:200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Inline elements (like SPAN, LABEL, etc.) are displayed so that their height and width are calculated by the browser based on their content. If you want to control height and width you have to change those elements' blocks.

`display: block;` makes the element displayed as a solid block (like DIV tags) which means that there is a line break after the element (it's not inline). Although you can use `display: inline-block` to fix the issue of line break, this solution does not work in IE6 because IE6 doesn't recognize inline-block. If you want it to be cross-browser compatible then look at this article: http://webjazz.blogspot.com/2008/01/getting-inline-block-working-across.html

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely try this way

```
.col-form-label{
  display: inline-block;
  width:200px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
label {
  width:200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

OR 

label {
  width:200px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

OR 

label {
  width:200px;
  display: inline-table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving width to Label is not a proper way. you should take one div or table structure to manage this. but still if you don't want to change your whole code then you can use following code.

```
label {
  width:200px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: "Giving width to Label in not a proper way" of controlling the width of a label element? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes .. Because when we want to create some layout or specific structure then div and table properties are provided to use. Label is not meant for giving width or height .. so if we use something which is not meant to do so .. it will start creating issues in some manner.

I hope i am making sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You can either give class name to all label so that all can have same width :

```
 .class-name {  width:200px;}
```

Example

```
.labelname{  width:200px;}
```

or you can simple give rest of label

```
label {  width:200px;  display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .princip{
        height: 190px ;
        width:190px ;
        border:  solid;
    }
    label{
        height: 190px !important;
        width:190px  !important;
        border:  solid;
        display: block;
    }
 </style>

    <div class="princip"  id="princip">
    
    
    <input id="rad1" type="radio" name="rad"/>
    
    <label class="lbl" id="lbl" for="rad1">
    
        <h1>fdgb</h1>
    <h2>sdfs</h2>
    </label>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS

label { display: block; width: 100px; }
The width attribute is deprecated, and CSS should always be used to control these kinds of presentational styles.