# Aligning the popup at the center of the text area in label element

Tags: javascript, css

I have a label element, whose width is much larger than the actual text.
So, the popover I am displaying is at the center of the label element but not at the center of the text area.

[image]

I want my `popover message` to be displayed directly under the text `label`. Can I attach a `onmouseover` event to the text `label` and not the dom?
Or can it be done using css?

Comment: The text of label isn't centered? Do you have actual code? Maybe in a [mcve]?

Comment: I won't be able to share the code, but the text in the label is right aligned in order to be close to the date element as seen in the snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a `span` element for the text within the `label` element and then add `hover` event on the `span` element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can adjust the **width** in your CSS file. 

 Check this link. It helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820603/7004388

Answer (score 0):

I can only show you what *I think* it should be like, and whatever you might've done wrong could not be addressed since no code is provided. Usually I vote to close questions without code, but I never made custom CSS tooltips before.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>tooltip</title>
  <style>
    .tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      display: inline-block;
      bottom: 1px;
      right: 0;
    }
    .tooltip .text {
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 0;
      font-size: 0;
      background-color: black;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 5px 0;
      border-radius: 6px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 0;
      top: 120%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -60px;
      transition: all .6s;
    }
    .tooltip .text::after {
      content: " ";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -5px;
      border-width: 5px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
    }
    .tooltip:hover .text {
      visibility: visible;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 120px;
      font-size: 16px;
      transition: all .6s;
    }
    label {
      position: relative;
      min-width: 200px;
      line-height: normal;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      vertical-align: text-top;
      outline: 1px dotted red;
      padding-bottom: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <section>
    <label for='txt1'>&nbsp;<b class="tooltip"><b class="text">Tooltip Text</b>Label Text</b>
    </label>
    <input id='txt1'>
  </section>
  <footer>&nbsp;</footer>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```