# CSS width: not working in label

Tags: css

I have written a simple form to test out the width in CSS. Regardless of the value I put for width, the borders still have the same width. Can somebody please help what am I missing?

```
<html  lang="en-US">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">
        label {  
          width: 10em;  
          border-color: brown;  
          border-width: .25em;  
          border-style: double;  
          margin-right: .5em;      
        }
      </style>  
      <title>Trying CSS </title>  
    </head>  

    <body>
      <form  action="#">  
        <fieldset  >  
          <label> Name </label>  
          <input type="text"/>  
          <label  >Contact</label>  
          <input type="text" />  
          <label >Phone</label>  
          <input  type="text" />  
          <button type="button">Submit </button>  
        </fieldset>  
      </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I control the width of a label tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820586/how-can-i-control-the-width-of-a-label-tag)

Comment: The label tag is  `display: inline;` as default, so width will have no working on it. You can set it with: `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;` to make width work. `position: absolute|fixed`, `float: left|right` can also make it work, but only use them when you know you need it.

Comment: may I ask why float makes it work too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css

```
label {  
width: 10em;  
border-color: brown;  
border-width: .25em;  
border-style: double;  
margin-right: .5em;      
float:left;
}
input{float:left;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--Inform the Browser that the document is HTML-->
<html  lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
label {  
width: 10em;  
border-color: brown;  
border-width: .25em;  
border-style: double;  
margin-right: .5em;      
float:left;
}
input{float:left;}
</style>  
<title>Trying CSS </title>  
</head>  
<body>
<form  action="#">  
<fieldset  >  
<label> Name </label>  
<input type="text"/>  
<label  >Contact</label>  
<input type="text" />  
<label >Phone</label>  
<input  type="text" />  
<button type="button">Submit </button>  
</fieldset>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why did you add the float: left? I am also keen to understand why the width in itself is not working

Comment: The Label element is defaulted to inline display mode.Inline elements don't accept a width property

Comment: don't want float:left you can use display:block

Comment: great, also does adding float change it to a block-like display? I understand how adding display: block helps

Comment: accepted, can you please let me know why float also makes it work?

Comment: float:left will collapse the default inline state

Answer (score 0):

Basically label is a tag. So what you should try is put a class inside the label tag and then write css for that . and for width try-- 
width=100%

Answer (score 0):

Use Padding instead of width

```
label {  
padding: 0 55px;  
border-color: brown;  
border-width: .5em;  
border-style: double;  
margin-right: .5em;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="labelborder">
     <label>sample text</label>
</div>
.labelborder {  
width: 10em;  
border-color: brown;  
border-width: .25em;  
border-style: double;  
margin-right: .5em;      
}
```

If label width accessing according to font-size only,if you want to increase without increasing font size,use above code like that,

Answer (score 0):

just add one more style to label as per your requirement

```
display: "inline-block"
```

or

```
display: "block"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `display:inline-block` to the label to give width